# How to disable mail server session in liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6

After starting **liferay 6.1 cebundled with Jboss 7.0.2**, I got a message in the console:

```
02:30:43,891 INFO  [stdout] (liferay/mail-1) 02:30:43,891 WARN  [MailEngine:500] Failed to connect to a valid mail serve
r. Please make sure one is properly configured. Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
```

Actually, I don't need mail server on my local machine , but I don't know how to disable it. The official documentation seams not to provide a hint about that , so could anyone give me a suggestion ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that unless you configure a mail server, it won't send email. Unless you want it to send email, you can just ignore that message.